# Searching for a contact using phone number

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am working on android app that receives a broadcast intent for incoming calls and incoming text messages.

It then is supposed to get the incoming number and perform a search on the users contacts using the incoming number.

This is more a less working, but I am having a slight problem. I have it working so that the number is searched in the contact list by, if it starts with + strips the first 3 characters and puts a 0 on the beginning, or just a does a search if it doesn't contain the +. However, I have a slight problem, that if the user enters spaces in the number then the app doesn't find the contact. For example, if I have a contact number saved as `07412xxxxxx` and the incoming number comes in as `07412xxxxxx` or `+447412xxxxxx`. However, if the contact number is saved as `07412 xxx xxx`and the incoming number is`07412xxxxxx`` then the number doesn't get recognised so it doesn't find the contacts name.

How can I perform the search to take all considerations of the number format. Below is the code I am currently using.

```
public String getContactNameFromNumber(String number)
    {

        if (number.startsWith("+"))
        {
            number = "0" + number.substring(3);
        }

        String contactName = null;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};
        String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { number };
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {

            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            cursor.close();
            return contactName;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a minor point, international country codes can have 1, 2 or 3 digits (see [here](http://countrycode.org/)), so you might need to check some more alternatives when dealing with numbers that start with a `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String selection = "REPLACE (" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + ", \" \" , \"\" ) = ?";
```

See [replace](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function.

Comment: Thanks for your help work perfectly. I would assign you the bounty but SO makes me wait for another 11 hours for some reason